# I want know know about sentence correction

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence

For example,
"The man felt his hair flutter and the tissues of his body drew tight as if he were standing at the centre of a vacuum."
And,
"He proved that if only germs were excluded of wounds, inflammation was averted."

I guessed it should be "DRAW TIGHT" in the first sentence and "EXCLUDED FROM WOUNDS"in the second one but I got both of them wrong.

Comment: The first correction is not a given; it's a matter of style. However, if *drew* is kept, there should be a comma after *flutter* because it's a second independent clause. I agree with the second correction. Although it changes the meaning slightly, the original version is not idiomatic; it means (or would more commonly be interpreted as so) that germs don't have wounds, rather than that wounds don't have germs. The original is not ungrammatical, but it is somewhat nonsensical. However, without knowing what the criteria of the test were, it's not possible to say what should have been done.

Comment: The first sentence is from the story *Dark They Were, and Golden-Eyed*, by Ray Bradbury, where it appears as:
"The man felt his hair flutter and the tissues of his body **draw** tight as if he were standing at the center of a vacuum." So you are correct and the answer key is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Peter Shor, are you ruling out the possibility of "drew tight" being correct merely on the ground that Ray Bradbury has written the other version of the sentence? I think "drew tight" is a fairly acceptable version as well.

Comment: @Stockfish: if the exercise says that something is wrong, and it's not that *drew tight* should be corrected to *draw tight*, then Ray Bradbury wrote his sentence with an error in it that neither Bradbury nor any of us can see. I don't believe that. Probably what happened is whoever wrote the exercise stole the questions from somewhere and made up the answers to the best of their very limited ability..

Comment: If a comma is put after flutter, then it makes sense...I got this one, but in the second question I was given the word "that" and "of wounds" underlined, so I chose OF WOUNDS as the wrong one,but the key said the mistake is in the first option, THAT...so what should I do??...

Answer (score 0):

The original is a little ambiguous, depending on your taste in comma usage. With a comma after flutter, it would imply that he first felt hair flutter, and then he felt tightened tissues as if in a vacuum: separate events. In this case, your choice of “draw tight” is inappropriate because he felt ... and then drew ... , both in the past tense.

The correction is based on a different interpretation. He felt fluttering hair AND tightened tissues, connected events both associated with the feeling of vacuum. It is implied that he felt his hair to flutter and his tissues to draw tight, both present tense. In this case, you are correct.

Jason has dealt with the germ question.